# Multi rows and columns in table

Tags: tables

Could you help me draw this table:

[image: Mut]

This is a MWE, it does not look similar at all but it is a starting point. I would do `\begin{tabular}{*{11}{c}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \small

        \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
            \toprule
            &  &  &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}  \\
            \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
            $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$& $L$ &  RMSE    &  MAE      & RMSE  & MAE \\
            \midrule
            0.01        & 0.006  & 30 & 1       & 0.9133    &    \textbf{0.9401}    &       &   \\
            0.01        & 0.002  & 50 & 2      &           & &0.8973       &  \textbf{0.9080} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}


    \end{table}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs} % provides \toprule, \bottomrule,\midrule, \cmidrule
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \small

        \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
            \toprule
            &  &  &   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ML}}  \\
            \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
            $\lambda$   & $\gamma$  & $n$& $L$ &  RMSE    &  MAE      & RMSE  & MAE \\
            \midrule
            0.01        & 0.006  & 30 & 1       & 0.9133    &    \textbf{0.9401}    &       &   \\
            0.01        & 0.002  & 50 & 2      &           & &0.8973       &  \textbf{0.9080} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}


    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Second mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{F}  \\ \hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{1} & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
& 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a recreation of that table. It differs in some of the columns, but, imho, this gives better results (maybe the second "Details" column could be aligned in a different way though).

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype\math[1]{>{$}#1<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}
  {
    ll \math{r}@{${}={}$} S[table-format=4]
    S[table-format=1.2] *4{S[table-format=2]} *2{S[table-format=.3]}
    S[table-format=2]@{\,}l
  }
  \toprule
  Algorithm & Details & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
    & {RMSE} & {Cov} & {Prec} & {Rec} & {F}
    & {Surp\textsuperscript{max}}
    & {Surp\textsuperscript{avg}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Time}
  \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{Parall} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sample} & n&100
    & 1.18 & 57 & 95 & 68 & 79 & .419 & .166
    & 10&m
  \\
  & & n&1000
    & 1.04 & 23 & 95 & 27 & 42 & .418 & .168
    & 1&h
  \\
  & \multirow{2}{*}{$k$-NN} & k&20
    & 1.00 & 31 & 97 & 38 & 54 & .421 & .176
    & 6&h
  \\
  & & k&30
    & 0.99 & 25 & 96 & 31 & 47 & .422 & .177
    & 19&h
  \\
  \cmidrule{1-4}
  & MSD & k&40
    & 0.98 & 23 & 96 & 28 & 43 & .423 & .175
    & 30&s
  \\
  $k$-NN & Cos & k&40
    & 1.02 & 21 & 96 & 26 & 41 & .426 & .180
    & 30&s
  \\
  & Pears & k&40
    & 1.01 & 25 & 95 & 30 & 46 & .425 & .170
    & 30&s
  \\
  \cmidrule{1-4}
  PMF & & f&100
    & 0.95 & 38 & 99 & 47 & 64 & .422 & .178
    & 45&s
  \\
  Mean & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
    & 1.13 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{}
    & 1&s
  \\
  Random & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
    & 1.52 & 81 & 86 & 89 & 88 & .432 & .155
    & 1&s
  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks sharp. Where does it differ?

Comment: @NaveganTeX In the second "Detail" column the numbers are right aligned (or better use an `S` column). The two "Surp" columns have leading zeros, the "Time" column adds a bit of space between numbers and units. All number columns use `S` type columns. Some of the columns are actually two columns (2nd "Details" and "Time" column), to get automatic spacing and the alignments. In all number columns the column heads are centred instead of left aligned to the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation!